# How to prove that $\int \varphi \, d\ell=-\int \operatorname{grad}\varphi\wedge dS $.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, electromagnetism

Let $\varphi$ be a scalar function having a continuous gradient throughout a region $R$ of space, let $\ell$ be the boundary curve of any surface $S$ lying entirely within the region $R$, then prove that:

### $$\int \varphi \, d\ell=-\int \operatorname{grad}\varphi\wedge dS $$

It look like Stokes's theorems but not exactly the same, I think we can prove it by reducing it to stokes theorem or by a proof similar  to the one of  stokes'theorem but I don't figure out how to do that, any hints?

This is a homework problem from Electromagnetism course.

Comment: There's no way to directly "reduce it to Stokes' theorem" since there may be no function whose curl is grad $ \varphi$.  I'd go with a "similar proof".

Comment: What book are you guys using? The identity looks a bit funny.

Comment: @JackyChong , Electromagnetic theory by Ferraro. it's an old book.

Comment: Is the problem from the book?

Comment: it is the first problem in the book 'D

Comment: I can't find a preview of the book online. Could you take a snapshot of the problem and post it?

Comment: I have copied it in the question area with just some symbols changed to more familliar ones.